# Como pasar datos de un ViewController a otro después del dismiss con programación

Tags: swift4

Desde el ViewController.swift (padre) presento un ViewController (hijo) con el siguiente código:

En ViewController.swift

```
let vc : UIViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "formulaView")
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

como puedo pasar un string de un text del hijo al padre al hacer el dismiss

En FormulaViewController.swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var ingrediente: UITextField!

@IBAction func closePopUp(_ sender: UIButton) {

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posibilidad sería delegar en la vista hijo la vista padre, pudiendo acceder desde la vista hijo a las propiedades de la vista padre.
La vista padre tendría la siguiente forma:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var text: String?

    @IBAction func mostrarHijo(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let formulaViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "formulaView") as! FormulaViewController
        formulaViewController.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.present(formulaViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

De esta forma, la clase hijo dispone de la clase padre en su código, pudiendo acceder a la propiedad `text` y modificar su valor:

```
class FormulaViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ingrediente: UITextField!
    var delegate: ViewController?

    @IBAction func closePopUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.text = self.ingrediente.text
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```